# Record all terminal interaction in a file (like a journal)

Tags: command-line

I am currently preparing for a pentesting project. My question is: Is there a way to log all interactions within a terminal in a file (e.g. for later examination). This is not about the typical redirection with > or >> or *tee* command.

I want for example log into a mysql shell from a bash terminal and record every input and output during the interaction into a file. Opening this file at the end of the process should show me every step within the bash shell, every inserted command in the mysql shell and every printed output of bash and mysql.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your workstation runs Linux and you are using gnome-terminal or its brethren,

```
man script
```

If your terminal is PuTTY, then use the built-in logging functionality.

Cut and paste have always worked for me in similar situations, followed by judicious editing before showing the transcript.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thx

Answer (score 0):

[GNU Xnee](https://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/)

is exactly what you need. it can record movement, keystrokes, mouse cursor movement , anything.